# How to connect live database from localhost(localmachine)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to connect live database from my localhost.

My code snippet is

```
$hostname="my ip address";
$userName="my_user";
$password="password";
$database="test_db";
$port="3306";

$con2=mysqli_connect($hostname,$userName,$password,$database,$port);

 if ($con2->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $con2->connect_error);
}else{
echo "<br> connection successfull----con2";
}
die;
```

I want to insert some data from my localhost to live database.

when am trying to connect using the above code snippet its showing error message like

> "Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in D:\xampp\htdocs\migration\migration.php on line 12
>   Connection failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Anybody could you please help me ?

I want to establish database connection from my localmachine.

Thanks.

Comment: This is mysql server issue and not php. Try to connect to your database from command line first and make needed changes

Comment: Make sure your credentials and host  name as well as port is correct.Use mysql GUI to confirm the credentials first.

Comment: You may not be able to do it as your hosting service may block access.  After all, they don't want anyone connecting to your databases, so some limit access to their own servers.  You may be better off creating a script of the changes you want to make and then applying it on the live machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your remote mysql server allows to connect externally by default its only accessible from localhost, if not then you need to check the bind-address setting in my.cnf file on your mysql server.

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

use

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0 or comment out the line if you want it to accessible from outside.

sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I am using for all my mySql localhost activities, and it works fine (assuming xampp is up and running)

```
    $LocalDB="myDeebee";
    $LocalUser="root";
    $LocalPassword="myPass";

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost",$LocalUser,$LocalPassword);
    $database=$LocalDB;

    if (!$conn){ 
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
    } else {

            // Whatever you want to do, insert, select, update

    }
```